# how to remove header from all screens in react native (stackNavigator)

Tags: react-native

I can not remove the header from all screens, I tried this setting below, but still the headers are not removed. Is it if I'm putting the navigationOptions settings incorrectly?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Home from './telas/Home'
import Login from './telas/Login'
import Cadastro from './telas/Cadastro'


const stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:Home,
  },
  Login:{
    screen:Login
  },
  Cadastro:{
    screen:Cadastro
  },
},
{
  navigationOptions:{
    header:null
  }
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(stackNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `defaultNavigationOptions` instead of `navigationOptions`.

```js
defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `headermode`

**headerMode** - Specifies how the header should be rendered:

- `float` - Render a single header that stays at the top and animates
  as screens are changed. This is a common pattern on iOS.
- `screen` - Each screen has a header attached to it and the header
  fades in and out together with the screen. This is a common pattern
  on Android.
- `none` - No header will be rendered.

**Exmaple**

```js
const ModalNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: { screen: Main },
    Login: { screen: Login },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    }
}
)
```

**Usage**

```js
const stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:Home,
  },
  Login:{
    screen:Login
  },
  Cadastro:{
    screen:Cadastro
  },
},
{
 headerMode: 'none'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify the headerMode in createStackNavigator.

Try using this

```
const stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:Home,
  },
  Login:{
    screen:Login
  },
  Cadastro:{
    screen:Cadastro
  },
},
{
  headerMode: 'none'
})
```